# Search member status for a specific word Python Discord nextcord

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, nextcord

I'd like to give them a role whenever a member's status changes to a certain word, and remove the role when they're no longer like that

I already known this event

```
@bot.event()
async def on_presence_update(befor, after):
    ...
```

but i dont know how to use it

Comment: `before` and `after` are both `discord.Member`s, so you can first check if the statuses are not equal to each other, to see if the status of a member changed `before.status != after.status`. And then you can check if it contains the word you're looking for and act accordingly.

Comment: but how i get the text in the status and not `online` or `dnd` or `idle` ?

Comment: My bad, its not `before.status`, but `before.activity`. You can get the name with `before.activity.name`. Just make sure the activity is not None